# Want to display the duplicate input

Tags: java, arraylist, input

I want my input number to be converted to an arraylist and then if it has any duplicates, it will say "duplicate" and print the duplicated numbers.

```
public class DuplicateWorld {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] numbers = new int[];

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter number");
            numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        Arrays.sort(numbers);
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
            for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.length; j++)
                if (numbers[i] == numbers[j])
                {
                    while (j < numbers.length && numbers[i] == numbers[j])
                        j++;
                    System.out.println("Duplicate" + numbers[i]);
                    i = j;
                }
     }
 }
```

Output that I get:
Please enter number
965499
0

Output that I want:
Please enter number
965499
Duplicate 9

Comment: Where are you printing "Duplicate"?

Comment: oh sorry! i forgot.. One second

Comment: I added the "duplicate" at the very bottom..Thanks

Comment: What's your input? You realize each digit needs to be separated. And you're only accepting 5 numbers, which means there's no room for the last `9`.

Comment: No actually I want the input to accept unlimited numbers..

Comment: Your array/loop only accepts 5.

Comment: I just copy pasted multi codes from different questions asked in Stack overflow to see if I can make what I want

Comment: So I removed that 5

Comment: It won't compile like that. Other than that, it works for me. I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: I want my unlimited input numbers to be converted to an arraylist and then if it has any duplicates, it will say "duplicate" and print the duplicated numbers

Comment: Ya sorry I'm a beginner and I'm trying to find some solutions.. But thanks a lot for helping

Comment: What do you mean by "unlimited numbers"? You have to stop at some point and process the input...

Comment: I mean no matter how many digits my one time input is

Comment: Your loop doesn't accept a single input. It's expecting each digit separately.

Comment: like 5 or 800,099 or 8 billion

Comment: oh ya u r right..Now I got ya.. I fixed the for loop ..instead of  i < numbers.length i put i<5..It's limited to 5 but it does work that way..

Comment: This should do it: `System.out.println("Please enter a number: "); System.out.println("Duplicates: " + Arrays.stream(String.valueOf(new Scanner(System.in).next()).split("")).map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())).entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1).map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList()));`

Comment: Please put this in the answers section so I can chose your answer..You r genius ! Couldn't be easier and cleaner than this

Comment: Is there anyway I can get in contact w u if I had more questions.. I have hard time solving my homework problems..I would appreciate it

Answer (score -1):

the reason you're getting 0 as your final output, is because it loops through your for loop all the way. the very last number is also a 9.

you need to instead, in your if statement, search the  entire array lists every time, because right now, it's getting to the last index, it's a 9, and you're asking it to look after that index, which in fact, there is nothing there, so it would be a 0.